# What is the plural of octopus?

Tags: plural-forms, latin

What is the plural of octopus? Is it octopuses, octopi or octopodes?

Normally in English it's supposed to be octopi, but when I type it, it has a red line under it (by the spell check), which means that it's incorrect. I also saw the word octopuses in my school's textbook. I got really confused about which one is correct.

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since there is some dispute over the correct plural, I voted to leave open.

Comment: I shall assume that the red line was added by your word processor's spell check function. That is dependent upon the dictionary which it uses and, as can be seen from the various answers below, they don't all *entirely* agree, though almost all of them agree that *octopi* is wrong, for the reasons explained by choster.

Comment: It's an exact duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-is-the-correct-plural-of-octopus

Comment: The fact that any particular spell-checker redlines a word does *not* mean the word in question is spelled incorrectly. Although difficult for most laymen to understand, *occasionally*, under the *most rarest of all possible circumstances*, a piece of software *may actually produce incorrect results*. Strange but true. Remember, you read it here first...

Comment: I suppose that referring to a group of these animals as "a whole buncha them suckers" would be considered gauche, as well as a bad pun?

Comment: @Closevoter: Given that there's widespread confusion about this, this shouldn't be "General reference". In addition, the OP has already used a "General reference", namely their spellchecker.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's incredibly easy to establish that "there is some dispute over the correct plural". Making this ***by definition*** an Off Topic "Primarily Opinion-Based" question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [*The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31118724) and [*The British National Corpus (BNC)*](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=31400916):

```
                    COCA             BNC
   octopuses      147 results       29 results
   octopi          44 results       11 results
   octopoda         4 results        0 results
   octopodes        2 results        3 results
```

The most common plural is *octopuses*.  Use that.

The alternative *octopi* is also somewhat common.  In fact, it's common enough that we should probably consider it standard as well, but because [*octopus* isn't actually derived from Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=octopus&allowed_in_frame=0), pluralizing it this way may rankle some feathers.  If you'd like to avoid criticism, avoid using this form.

We'll discount *octopoda* entirely since all four results are from Orson Scott Card's *Lost Boys*, in which fictional characters discuss the proper plural of *octopus*.

The least common on the list is *octopodes*.  Although you can make an argument that this plural is more correct than *octopi*, the fact is few people know it and fewer people use it.  If you pluralize *octopus* this way, you'll draw more attention to how you're saying it than what you're saying.  *Octopodes* probably isn't common enough to be considered standard, and worse, it may fail to communicate entirely.

The verdict?  **If you want to communicate, use *octopuses*.**  Save the other plurals for when you want to use words like toys.

Answer (score 33):

Some English words borrowed directly from other languages retain the plural form of the other language. For example, *fermata* is pluralized as *fermate*, and *cirrhosis* becomes *cirrhoses*.

The most familiar examples are words taken directly from Latin, of which there are at least hundreds: *persona* / *personae*, *matrix* / *matrices*, *fulcrum* / *fulcra*, and so forth, but there are examples from Greek, Italian, and so on. Over time, some plurals have been regularized, especially in American English, and especially when referring to modern concepts as opposed to ancient— there are [far more *database schemas* than *database schemata*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=database%20schemas,%20database%20schemata&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,database%20schemas;,c0;.t1;,database%20schemata;,c0) out in the wild.

Because the Latin irregular plurals are most common, and sound loftier than the regular plural, there is a tendency to [hypercorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection) the plural of any word ending in *-us* and *-um* in particular, even when there is no historical basis for it. And thus, [Oxford tells us](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/octopus)

> The standard plural in English of **octopus** is **octopuses**. However, the word **octopus** comes from Greek, and the Greek plural form **octopodes** is still occasionally used. The plural form **octopi** is mistakenly formed according to rules for Latin plurals, and is therefore incorrect.

At some point, of course, any "incorrect" usage that becomes popular enough becomes "correct," and so it is that various dictionaries will include *octopi* (and *ethoi* and *diplomae* and so on) as acceptable plurals. [American Heritage](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=octopus) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cactus) list it as an acceptable alternative. M-W has an [Ask the Editor segment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFyY2mK8pxk&feature=kp) on the matter.

Comment: Cactus comes from Latin *cactus*, which came from Greek *kaktos*. Although the original was Greek, *cactus* was Latin, so I can't see why *cacti* is wrong.

Comment: The difference is English `cactus` was borrowed directly from Latin, so Latin rules can apply. `Octopus` is just a Latinized spelling of a word borrowed directly from Greek, so Greek rules apply.

Comment: Hypercorrection, blah. I maintain that the formation of plurals by changing "-us" (or homophones of "-us", such as "Elvis") to "-i" is a standard mechanism **in English.** So the source of the word is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, @kundor there are so many clowns here, it’s like two circi.  I had to take three bi to get here. (Because we wouldn’t say “circuses” or “buses”.)

Comment: Just as there are multiple ways to form adverbs from adjectives, or other such transformations ("-ity" vs. "-hood" vs. "-ness" for example), and not all of them work equally well for all words, there are multiple ways to form plurals, and most words have a preferred version. So just as you'd say "maturity" over "matureness", but "niceness" instead of "nicity", you'd pick "circuses." Nonetheless, I claim they're both valid English mechanisms and the choice is determined word-by-word, not solely by its provenance. @Scott

Comment: @kundor, changing *-us* to *-i* is not a productive plural form in English. Call it "standard" all you want, but that won't change this. It appears only when a plural is a loan word from a language that does have this approach, as a hypercorrection (e.g. *octopi*) or as a joke (e.g. *virii* is a joke plural for computer viruses, much as *boxen* is a joken plural of *box* in the sense of "computer").

Comment: The link you provide to Oxford notes that Octopus doesw come to us from Latin.  So wikipedia's explanation is better.  The reason octopi is wrong is not that the word is greek rather than latin, it's the fact that octopus is not a second declenation latin noun.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I wasn't disputing octopus - I said the same thing in my own answer. I was commenting on the line "various dictionaries will include octopi (and cacti and so on)" that suggested *cacti* was similarly wrong.

Answer (score 9):

As snailplane pointed out in the comments, *octopus* is derived from Greek, and so the correct plural would be *octopodes*, **not** *octopi*.

From [Oxford Dictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/octopus):

> The standard plural in English of *octopus* is *octopuses*. However, the word *octopus* comes from Greek and the Greek plural form *octopodes* is still occasionally used. The plural form *octopi*, formed according to rules for some Latin plurals, is incorrect.

And from the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=octopus&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **octopus** (n.)
>       1758, genus name of a type of eight-armed cephalopod mollusks, from Greek *oktopous*, literally "eight-footed," from *okto* "eight" (see eight) + *pous* "foot" (see foot (n.)). Proper plural is *octopodes*, though *octopuses* probably works better in English. *Octopi* is from [the] mistaken assumption that *-us* in this word is the Latin noun ending that takes *-i* in plural.

As pointed out above, *octopuses* would probably be acceptable in all but the most formal of circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Even one source will change its answer to a question such as this as time passes and language evolves.  For example:

- The 1998 edition of Chambers Dictionary gives *octopuses* as the main answer, and lists *octopodes* as an archaic form.
- I know that earlier editions of the Chambers Twentieth Century Dictionary did not have the 'archaic' annotation.
- [Their web site](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=octopus) currently only lists *octopuses*.

As to the red line to which you refer, I shall assume that it was added by your word processor's spell check function. That is, of course, dependent upon the dictionary which it uses and, as can be seen from the other answers, they don't all entirely agree, though almost all of them agree that octopi is wrong, for the reasons explained by choster.

Answer (score 1):

"octopuses" and "octopi" are valid plurals for "octopus".  I prefer "octopi" -- it sounds more entertaining, without risking a *double entendre*.

Spell-checkers are often incorrect.  For example, good spell checkers do not include the word "calender", because misspellings of "calendar" are far more common than correct usages of "calender".

Also, most spell-checkers are implemented by building a list of common base words, and adding some rules for common variations on those base words.  (*Programming Pearls* has an essay on how combining this approach with "hashtables" allows spell-checking large numbers of words, while using surprisingly little memory.)  This means that every unusual ending needs to be specially added to the dictionary.  For example, the dictionary could include "octopus" and have a rule that "octopus" + "es" is also a valid word.  If nobody bothered to add "octopi" to the dictionary, it would be marked in red by your spell-checker.

By the way, StackExchange's spell-checker complains about "StackExchange" and "hashtable", but not about "octopuses" or "octopi".

Comment: Please cite your source in support of your assertion that _octopi_ is valid.